# How to add points to line at every polygon/polyline intersection and have attribute table including distance of new line sements

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line

I am working with polyline shapefile.

I need to add point data at every intersection of polyline/polygon which was no problem->simple intersection.

Problem is, points were not added to the ends (start/end) of each polyline. I am working on a basic license and am very limited to what tools are available. Ideally I would use linear referencing tools, or geometric network but neither one is available to me. I will also need the distance of each new (line segment), I do not want to break up the lines into actual line segments if possible.

Suggestions?

Comment: One suggestion that may be faster than "working around" the lack of the linear referencing tool availability in Arc (such as dissolving the line, densifying points, running calculations on that etc.) would be to just use the LRS plugin for QGIS which does exactly what you want to do in a few clicks.  http://blazek.github.io/lrs/

Comment: I think you have access to linear referencing with basic license- details at https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/linear-referencing-toolbox-licensing.htm.

Comment: I got it, now I have a problem with duplicate records in the output table?? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assumed you have got the intersection points!
Now let's see how to extract first and last points of the lines-

1. Add four fields in the attribute table viz `FirstPointX`, `FirstPointY`, `LastPointX` and `LastPointY` with data type of double.
2. Run python commands serially on the previously created fields as `!Shape!.firstPoint.X`,  `!Shape!.firstPoint.Y` , `!Shape!.lastPoint.X`and `!Shape!.lastPoint.Y` - this will populate those fields with x and y coordinate of the first and last points of that line.
3. Export this attribute table as dbf or other format and use Add X Y data tool to create points from this table- these points are the reputed first and last points.
4. You may need to remove duplicate points- for this follow [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67035/how-to-remove-duplicate-features-with-the-same-geometry-in-arcmap) post.
5. Now join the previously created points from Intersection operation.If need to track attribute you may use Spatial Join tool.

This is all!

---

EDIT as paul suggested.

If you have ArcMap 10.2.1 or higher then you can use [Add Geometry Tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm) to add first and last point in the attribute table that it will discard 1 and 2 step.

Comment: @ 10.2.1, [`Add Geometry Attributes`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm#L_) was added, which can replace the 8 operations of steps 1-2. If OP had access to Advanced license, he could replace steps 1-3 with [`Feature Vertices to Points`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm).

Comment: @ Paul OP did not mention arcmap version but mentioned license level i.e. BASIC. So i opted for general solution.

Comment: Not knocking your answer in the slightest! Other people might come across this thread later with different version/license, so I thought I'd comment what is possible.

Comment: Where is a distance (length? distance along line?) in this solution?

Comment: @FelixIP Thanks,I think there is no problem in using Linear Referencing with basic license- as i commented earlier.

Comment: I got it, now I have a problem with duplicate records in the output table??  Thanks!

Comment: use Add XY Coordinates tool and create another text field that contains concatenated form of X  and Y. Now Dissolve by this field- this will delete all duplicate points.  Details at  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26921/remove-spatially-duplicate-features-using-modelbuilder